# Tomcat application hangs when accessing a NFS mount

Tags: java, tomcat, nfs

A Tomcat application stalls during startup. By looking at the call stack, I can see it's stuck at its main thread:

```
"RMI Scheduler(0)": awaiting notification on [0xe9892698]
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:158)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1987)
at java.util.concurrent.DelayQueue.take(DelayQueue.java:160)


"main": running, holding [0xe5818b78, 0xe9889690, 0xe98880e8, 0xbad69fc0, 0xbad69f20, 0xbad663b8, 0xbad16508]
at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.lock0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.tryLock(FileChannelImpl.java:881)
at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.tryLock(FileChannel.java:962)
at java.util.logging.FileHandler.openFiles(FileHandler.java:396)
at java.util.logging.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:270)
at com.xyxy.visualizer.util.DsvLogger.<init>(DsvLogger.java:32)
...
```

Following is the code of the DsvLogger class.

```
package com.xyxy.visualizer.util;

import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.util.logging.Formatter;
import java.util.logging.Handler;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter;

public class DsvLogger
extends Logger {
private static final String LOG_LOCATION = "/nfsdir1/xyxy/webapps/logs"
private static DsvLogger instance;

private DsvLogger() throws SecurityException {
    super("DSVLogger", null);
    String filename = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss_").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()) + ".log";
    FileHandler fh = null;
    try {
        fh = new FileHandler(LOG_LOCATION + filename, false);
        fh.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
        this.addHandler(fh);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("file handler not initialized for file: " + LOG_LOCATION + filename);
    }
}

public static DsvLogger getInstance() throws SecurityException {
    DsvLogger dsvLogger = instance == null ? (DsvLogger.instance = new DsvLogger()) : instance;
    return dsvLogger;
    }
}
```

It sets the log path to a NFS directory. there were some issues with the NFS server recently but Tomcat itself can write its log messages without issue (on the same NFS share but different directory).

Tomcat and the application run on a Solaris 10 server with nfs vers=3, while the NFS server is running both nfs3 and nfs4 on Redhat.

It's very revealing that under the log location, the file created by the application does not conform to the name specified in the code, but with a ".lck" suffix:

2017-10-12_05-00-36_.log.lck

the size is 0.
and when I try to view the log file created, the cat command freezes.

Anyone have idea what might went wrong with this application?

Comment: **Any** application can stall when accessing an NFS mounted file system. I've seen entire development departments do that when NFS caught a cold. Solution: don't. Applications should use local file systems only. Especially mission-critical ones like Tomcat.

Comment: That's absolutely good point. But in a organization where NFS is prevailent  - a lot of applications are entangled in the NFS. It's hard to convince the high "architects" to make that transistion. As a matter fact (don't laugh - ), the binaries of entire application and Tomcat are running on the NFS :(

Comment: You need to convince them they've been drastically wrong all these years. It's not just NFS: any remote filesystem is a frequent point of failure. Exhibit this problem to them.

Comment: the problem is now mitigated by upgrading NFS server to V4.